# Angular2 Component variable being modified by multiple promises

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I have a searchbox which is querying the server on `keydown` event, as long as the query string is longer then 2 characters. Code below is typescript and from my search component. `entries.items` is directly used in the template html for this component. The code is stripped down from other stuff focusing on the problem area.

```
public Search(query: string)
{
        if (query && query.length > 2)
        {
            var ref = this;
            ref.entries.items = [];

            this.SearchService.Search(query).then(response => {
                let list = JSON.parse(response._body).items;
                list.forEach(element => {
                    ref.entries.items.push(element.details);
                });
            });
        }
 }
```

When the user keeps on typing to get the final work (*ex: s - st - sta- stac - stack*) we keep on querying and end up in a state where the items are modified multiple times and I'm seeing the same result appended multiple times (ex: if there's one result for stack - it's displayed for *sta*, *stac* and *stack* search queries) - so we're in a state of promises returning and simultaneously modifying the items. It kind of feels like I need a lock, but I'm guessing there's a better way of doing this. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you handle input changes?

You're using angular2, let's use rxjs approach. 
In your sample you lack of importantest thing - switching to another stream. It means that if new value from input is received then other requests are ignored.

Here is tutorial: https://alligator.io/angular/real-time-search-angular-rxjs/
Or demo: https://embed.plnkr.co/giSBvwKpq04qfRBLDY8x/?show=preview

You need to create something like that:

```
Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keydown')
  .debounceTime(500)
  .switchMap(query => Observable.fromPromise(SearchService.Search(query)))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even better solution:

```
this.form.get('searchbox')
        .valueChanges
        .debounceTime(400)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap(query => Observable.fromPromise(SearchService.Search(query)))
        .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```